# How to display value in label when button click using angularjs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, data-binding

I have an aspx page with button group and label. I want to display selected button value in the paragraph tag. 
Here is my controller code

```
$scope.GetID = function (uGuid) {
    $scope.uid=uGuid;
    alert($scope.uid);
}
```

And my aspx code is

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="outlet in Outlets">
 <td><button data-ng-click="GetID(outlet.uGuid);">{{outlet.PartnerName}}
  </button>
 </td>
```

```
<p>{{uid}}</p>
```

The problem is that value display in the paragraph tag correctly. but it automaticaly ignored.Value Just display and reloaded.

Comment: What do you mean but it automatically ignored ?

Comment: Really **unclear what you're asking**. What behavior are you looking for?

Comment: code is working properly what excactly you want us to solve? please [find this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9358/)

Comment: " but it automaticaly ignored.Value Just display and ignored." Explain this

Comment: i want to pass the {{uid}} value as a parameter. I tried i display  {{uid}} to a textbox and get the value from textbox  Private Sub btnDisplayOrder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayOrder.Click
       Dim aID As String = outletids.Text
       End sub  outletids : is my textbox id . but the value shows null.

Answer (score 0):

Change controller.js

```
$scope.Outlets = JSON.parse(Outlets);  
    $scope.GetID = function (uGuid) {
        $scope.Outlets = JSON.parse(Outlets);           
        $scope.uid = uGuid;
        debugger;
        alert($scope.uid);
    }
```

The problem is that the  $scope.Outlets is getting reloaded. so include

```
   $scope.Outlets = JSON.parse(Outlets);
```

inside button click.